# Getting color from xml values

Tags: c#, xml, colors

I have an xml which is generated automatically from .pptx. I want to get the color of the font  of the letters. If the color is basic (yellow, red, black etc.), I get for example #FF0000, which is ok.
But, if the color is light yellow or some other not basic color, in the xml there is this:

```
<a:solidFill>
    <a:schemeClr val="accent6">
        <a:lumMod val="60000"/>
        <a:lumOff val="40000"/>
    </a:schemeClr>
</a:solidFill>
```

This is generated if the letters are pink.
Is there any way I can get the color in this format #ff0000 by those values?
I work in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`schemeClr` denotes that the color is related the users current theme (I'm unsure if this means Powerpoint theme, or Windows theme), so there would be no way to tell from that what the color was meant to be. You would have to look up `accent6` elsewhere in the document.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.schemecolor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but maybe this is integer representation? So you need to read int for val and then use `Color.FromArgb(val)`.